# Postman Accept header not in request

Tags: json, interceptor, postman, referer

I'm using Postman with the Interceptor extension to perform a POST request.

My request contains an Origin header to be able to avoid CORS errors. The `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I receive json, so I had to add the `Accept header` with value `application/json`.

The API I call wants me to add the Referer header as well, so I do that. When I send the request, the `Accept header` is not in the raw request. When I remove the `Referer header`, the `Accept header` shows up in the raw request.

Is this a bug in Postman/Interceptor or am I doing something against 'the rules' of sending http requests?

Comment: Same just happened to me with an `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding` and `Accept-Language` header: the latter was silently dropped by Postman. Disabling `Referer` _or_ `Accept-Encoding` did the trick, but I don't like it.